# User activity log to log old and new value using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have task to log user activity of the user for the project. So the requirement is to log all the changes to the database ie. any updates to the database has to be logged.

**Example:**

> User1(who is assumed to be admin) tries to update firstname, lastname
>   of user2 then I should be logging messages like: User1 updated
>   firstname of user2 from "oldValue" to "newValue"

I am using **MVC** with **entityframework** and **log4net** for logging user activity.

Since I am using model to populate my view I can get the old model and new model. But how can I compare the model and find the differences to log it?

I first thought I can override Equal method of the class but he equal method returns a bool value which will only give me true or false.

But I would like to know old and new values. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it solved by looping through each properties inside a class and get values for the property from both the objects and compare.

Here is the code:

```
Type types = typeof(ModelName);

//Loop through each properties inside class and get values for the property from both the objects and compare
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in types.GetProperties())
{
    string newValue = string.Empty;
    string oldValue = string.Empty;
    if (types.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(modelnew, null) != null)
        newValue = types.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(modelnew, null).ToString();
    if (types.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(modelOld, null) != null)
        oldValue = types.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(modelOld, null).ToString();

    if (newValue.Trim() != oldValue.Trim()) //if both values are not same
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue.Trim()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue.Trim()))//if both values are not null
        {
            //log the update ie. value is updated from oldValue to newValue
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldValue.Trim()))//else if only oldvalue is not null
        {
            //log - oldvalue has been deleted for property.name
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newValue.Trim()))
        {
            //log- newValue has been added for property.name
        }
    }
}
```